# Parsing XML in Python with regex

Tags: python, xml, regex

I'm trying to use regex to parse an `XML` file (in my case this seems the simplest way).

For example a line might be:

```
line='<City_State>PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906</City_State>'
```

To access the text for the tag City_State, I'm using:

```
attr = re.match('>.*<', line)
```

but nothing is being returned.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am compelled to link [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845).

Comment: Using a proper XML library isn't hard once you find a library you like. I found [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) the nicest to use one in the standard library, and [untangle](https://github.com/stchris/untangle) the easiest (it converts XML into regular dictionaries/lists etc)

Comment: Dang, @Johnsyweb beat me to it!

Comment: >Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? A: you are trying to parse XML using regular expressions.

Comment: I have tried ElementTree before and I am getting memory issues.  The file size is 250Mb.  Since the XML file I am parsing is very simple, I figured it is easier to use regex.

Comment: Try `etree.iterparse` (e.g. lxml.etree), or SAX events. Both have very small memory requirements.

Comment: Reopening this question - it's a perfectly valid question as to why `re.match` isn't working. Linking the ubiquitous [X]HTML-regex question adds nothing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You normally don't want to use `re.match`. [Quoting from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use [search()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead (see also [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)).

Note:

```
>>> print re.match('>.*<', line)
None
>>> print re.search('>.*<', line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f666238>
>>> print re.search('>.*<', line).group(0)
>PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906<
```

---

Also, why parse XML with regex when you can use something like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) :).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> line='<City_State>PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906</City_State>'
>>> soup = BS(line)
>>> print soup.find('city_state').text
PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906
```

Answer (score 9):

Please, just use an XML parser like ElementTree

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> line='<City_State>PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906</City_State>'
>>> ET.fromstring(line).text
'PLAINSBORO, NJ 08536-1906'
```

Answer (score 0):

re.match returns a match only if the pattern matches the entire string. To find substrings matching the pattern, use re.search.

And yes, this is a simple way to parse XML, but I would highly encourage you to use a library specifically designed for the task.

Comment: It would only be "a simple way to parse XML" if it actually _did_ parse XML. Which it doesn't. (See: lack of support for detecting comment or CDATA blocks; for handling character entities; etc etc etc).

Comment: Minor point: `re.match` is left side anchored but does not have to consume the entire string.  Very loosely, given regexp `X`, `re.match` is like `re.search` using `^X` (but not `^X$`).  There are other differences, particularly with strings containing newlines; see documentation link in [Haidro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18168699/1256452).